# How can I update my languages from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, automation, internationalization, localization

After installing Ubuntu and updating the system, the first thing I usually do is make sure that all applications use the preferred locale. To do so, I start *Language Support* from the Dash which automatically downloads the remaining localisation packages:

[image]

This works well, but as I'm doing most of my Ubuntu post-installation work from the terminal, I'd like to do this from the terminal, too.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this command (I used English (`en`) in the example):

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en language-pack-en-base
```

---

Depending on the desktop environment you use, you also need those:

For **Gnome/Unity**

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base
```

For **KDE**:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-en-base
```

---

Also, there is a utility to check which programs you have installed and then determines the needed language packages. It will also cover Firefox and Thunderbird, for example. It is intended to use with `apt-get` together:

```
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support -l en)
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks, this will make everything go even faster.

Comment: Since the second package is a dependency of the first, just this also works: `sudo apt install language-pack-en`

Answer (score 4):

According to [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale), you first edit the file `/etc/default/locale`, or use:

```
$ update-locale LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

and then you run:

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Thanks, but that one didn't work. For instance, Firefox still uses the default language.